# JCA Glassfish to JBoss/Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, glassfish, wildfly

I need to be able to deploy *.ear* file containing *.rar* resource adapter to `jBoss/Wildfly`. It has been working previously for GF. Problem is that in my *.war* file (which is also part of the .ear) I have this `web.xml`:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>eis/host</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
  <lookup-name>java:/env/eis/host-somehost</lookup-name>
</resource-ref>
```

and jBoss cannot find the resource:

```html
Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"HostConnector-ear-1.17-SNAPSHOT\".\"HostConnector-war-1.17-SNAPSHOT\".env.eis.host is missing          [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.eis.host]"]}
```

I have created element in standalone.xml, but seams the naming is wrong or what:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:2.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="Host-ra">
                <archive>
                    HostConnector-1.17-SNAPSHOT-local#HostConnector-rar-1.17-SNAPSHOT.rar
                </archive>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name=".....jca.spi.HostManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/env/eis/host-somehost" enabled="true" use-java-context="false" pool-name="java:jboss/env/eis/host-somehost"/>
                </connection-definitions>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```

If I have *.rar* packaged in *.ear* is it enough to just deploy with *ra.xml*? Where is the resource-adapter JNDI name defined?

Comment: I have discussed it also [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/933348#933348), but still I'm not able to resolve it. More likely I'm missing some config file or what. Although I understand what the message means I cannot find way to make it work.

Comment: which JBoss version are you using? JNDI name conventions have changed in JBoss 7

Comment: I'm on Wildfly 8.0.0 and up. It seams my biggest problem is that deployed resource adapter is not visible in JNDI view. Can you name some differences, although I don't expect the name itself to be the problem.

Comment: It seems it is not finding the resource other than resolving the JNDI. Have you tried to defining the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`? Have a look at this document on [class loading in wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)

Comment: I have played with jboss-deployment-structure.xml as well. I was wondering if I will use jboss console to define resource adapter, it let you define JNDI name for that resource adapter. But even when enabled it is not visible in JNDI view. What is the connection between resource adapter definition and deployed .rar file? I tried to use <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated> , but I was not succesful(which is anyway by default set to false). The .war cannot see the RA, because it is not visible in JNDI view. Maybe the loading order matters?

Comment: Resolved there was typo in ra.xml, which was magically ignored by Glassfish and not by JBoss, it was some "transitive" error

Comment: @Zveratko Can you post and accept the answer so this question does not show up on searches for unanswered questions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in ra.xml, where the packages names were not properly set and Glassfish ignored this while JBoss failed. fixing the factories package name fixed that issue.